# Bootstrap 3.2 dropdown menus don't work on ipad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have spent all day searching for the answer to this problem and tried dozens of potential solutions and I haven't been able to get them to work.  The problem seems to be that my top level menu item is also a clickable item and so when I click on it on the ipad it just goes to that page.  Any hint on what changes I can make to the code to make it work would rock.  My development page is here:  http://skydivetemple.com/index2.php
Thanks a million for any help!

```
    <?php
    define( 'HTTP_URL', 'http://skydivetemple.com' );
    define( 'HTTPS_URL', 'https://skydivetemple.com' );
    define( 'DEV_DIR', '' );
    define( 'DEV_ASSETS_DIR', DEV_DIR.'/skydivetemple/' );
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <title><?php echo $pageMetaTitle; ?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pageMetaDescription; ?>" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pageMetaKeywords; ?>" />

        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo DEV_ASSETS_DIR; ?>js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo DEV_ASSETS_DIR; ?>js/html5.js" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo DEV_ASSETS_DIR; ?>css/gt.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo DEV_ASSETS_DIR; ?>css/skydive.css" >
        <link href="<?php echo DEV_ASSETS_DIR; ?>css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Animation Style -->
        <link href="<?php echo DEV_ASSETS_DIR; ?>css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/"><img src="<?php echo DEV_ASSETS_DIR; ?>images/logo.png" alt="Skydive Temple Logo" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 phn hidden-xs">
        <span>Call Now</span>
        <p><a href="tel:8773948282">1-877-EXIT-282</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 head-btn">
        <a href="<?php echo HTTPS_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/buy/buy_online.php?s=gc" class="btn btn-default">Buy as a Gift</a>
        <a href="<?php echo HTTPS_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/buy/buy_online.php" class="btn btn-default">Book it now</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="tel:8773948282" class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 1-877-394-8282</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/Skydiving_Prices.php">Prices</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/Tandem_Skydiving.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="true">Tandem</a>
                <ul  onClick="return true" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/Tandem_Skydiving_Video.php"> Tandem Video Package </a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/Tandem_Skydiving_Specials.php"> Tandem Specials </a></li>
/li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/Skydive_Temple_Tandem_Waiver.php"> Review Tandem Waiver </a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/buy/buy_online.php"> Sign up today! </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/Learn_To_Skydive.php" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="true">Learn To Skydive</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="<?php echo HTTP_URL.DEV_DIR; ?>/Learning_To_Skydive_Details.php"> Student Page </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

.....

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get your problem. Would you elaborate?

Comment: Out of the box, Bootstrap's navigation is click/tap only and the top level triggers are not links, they are the triggers to open the drop down. If you change this to :hover, since :hover doesn't exist on touch devices, then tapping will open the page. What is happening is normal. 

One idea, is to detect, with JS, whether or not a device is a touch device and then on desktop, have it work as it is now, but on touch devices, add that top level link to the dropdown and have the menu behave as a click menu.

Comment: The dropdown menus weren't showing at all on the ipad.  I finally figured it out - I made the top menu line not a link and moved that link down, and added onClick="return true"  - I had to do both or the menus wouldnt even appear on an ipad..